# Onsen UI (Windows Phone) - PullHook element doesn't work

Tags: html, cordova, internet-explorer, windows-phone, onsen-ui

I am using the onsen ui pull-hook (took the example from their site) in a cordova app. It works as expected in android, however on windows phone nothing happens. The state always stays "Pull down to refresh".

```
<ons-pull-hook ng-action="findUsers($done)" var="loader">
    <span ng-switch="loader.getCurrentState()">
    <span ng-switch-when="initial"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-down-a"></ons-icon> Pull down to refresh</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="preaction"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-up-a"></ons-icon> Release to refresh</span>
    <span ng-switch-when="action"><ons-icon size="35px" spin="true" icon="ion-load-d"></ons-icon> Loading data...</span>
    </span>
</ons-pull-hook>

<ons-list>
<ons-list-item ng-show="users.length === 0">
    <div class="info">
        Pull down to refresh
    </div>
</ons-list-item>
<ons-list-item class="item" ng-repeat="user in users">
    <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="80px">
            <img ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/?{{user.rand}}" class="item-thum" />
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
            <p class="item-desc">{{ user.username }}</p>
        </ons-col>
    </ons-row>
</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Could it be that this element doesn't support WP so far? If so, does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: What type of app are you building? Are you building for "wp8" or "windows" platform?

Comment: Windows Universal. (I know that wp8 is not supported by onsen)

Comment: You can check how Onsen UI templates are made. Pull Hook works in Windows Universal if you do the same than in the templates (ng-csp, windows shim...).